# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{S_1(n)S_5(n)-S_3(n)²}{S_7(n)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If $S_k(n)=\sum_{r=1}^n r^k$, then compute

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{S_1(n)S_5(n)-S_3(n)²}{S_7(n)}$

($n$ defined on all natural)

What I did -

$S_1(n)$ is a  term of degree 2. $S_5(n)$'s last would be $n^5$ so in the product of $S_5(n)$ with $S_1(n)$ the maximum power of $n$ would be 7. Similarly in the denominator $S_7(n)$ will also have maximum power of 7. What I was thinking of was to take the $n^7$ common and reduce it but now I am stuck because in $S_3(n)²$ the maximum power of $n$ will be $8$.

Any hint will also be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$S_{\gamma}(n) \sim \frac{n^{\gamma+1}}{\gamma+1}~~~~(*)$$

So $$L=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{S_1(n) S_{5}(n)-S^2_{3}(n)}{S_7(n)}= \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(n^2/2)(n^6/6)-(n^4/4)^2}{n^8/8}= \frac{(1/12)-(1/16)}{(1/8)}=\frac{1}{6}.$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: You've already made the observation that $S_k(n) = O(n^{k+1})$ as $n \to \infty$. Can you make this more precise? See if you can evaluate the limit $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{S_k(n)}{n^{k+1}} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{r = 1}^{n}\left(\dfrac{r}{n}\right)^k$ in terms of $k$. If you've seen Riemann sums, this will be easy. If not, there are probably still ways to do this.

From there, you have $\displaystyle\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{S_1(n)S_5(n)-S_3(n)^2}{S_7(n)} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{\tfrac{S_1(n)}{n^2}\tfrac{S_5(n)}{n^6}-\left(\tfrac{S_3(n)}{n^4}\right)^2}{\tfrac{S_7(n)}{n^8}}$ which should be easy to compute.